# How to update an old MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, software-update, mac-appstore

I got a MacBook Air (13 inches, early 2014) from someone that is not using it anymore.  It's running  Yosemite, version 10.10.5.

I want to update it to a more recent version. Unfortunately, I don't have any update possible in the app store. Even if I had updates in the app store, I can't connect to it. I use the good credentials to connect but it says I'm using the wrong one. (It works in iTunes or on other Apple products).

So I'm trying to find a way to update this Mac without using the App Store.

Do you know how I could do it? And what is the most recent version of macOS that I can have on this Mac?

Comment: You can run macOS 11 (Big Sur) on a 2014 MBA.  Have you tried Internet Recovery by holding `Cmd-R` while booting?

Comment: The real problem is why App Store isn't accepting your AppleID. Create a new question (or edit this one), describing exactly what you do, and what error messages you get.